# Creating QPainter object by passing pixmap via ".pixmap()" causes: "QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted"

Tags: python, qpainter, qlabel, qpixmap, pyqt6

Ive just recently started to use PyQt6. I am trying to make a custom UI-element so i am (trying) to use QPainter. However even the example code on https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyqt6-bitmap-graphics/ doesn't work and outputs **QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted**. (I'll paste the code with a few added comments down below)

It seems that when i create an `QPainter` object by passing it the label's pixmap by using `self.label.pixmap()` something is happening that is causing the error.

Commenting the two following lines (`painter.drawLine(10, 10, 300, 200)` and `painter.end()` does not stop the error from occuring

**However**, when i pass it the `canvas` object directly, and then assign the `canvas` object to `label` it works. But now i would have to reassign the `canvas` to `label` everytime i want to update it.

This is the example code from the website:

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # create widget containing the pixmap
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        # create the pixmap
        canvas = QtGui.QPixmap(400, 300)

        # set the pixmap to the label
        self.label.setPixmap(canvas)

        # i dont really know what this does but it was in the example code
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

        self.draw_something()

    def draw_something(self):
        # create the painter and tell it what pixmap to draw on
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.label.pixmap())

        # draw a line
        painter.drawLine(10, 10, 300, 200)

        # end / delete the printer
        painter.end()




app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

And this is my Version which somewhat works:

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # create widget containing the pixmap
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        # create the pixmap
        self.canvas = QtGui.QPixmap(400, 300)

        # this was not in the example code but without it the background is just black and the line therefore not visible
        self.canvas.fill(QtGui.QColor("white"))

        # i dont really know what this does but it was in the example code
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

        self.draw_something()

        # set the pixmap to the label
        self.label.setPixmap(self.canvas)

    def draw_something(self):
        # create the painter and tell it what pixmap to draw on (in this case directly to canvas obj)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.canvas)

        # draw a line
        painter.drawLine(10, 10, 300, 200)

        # end / delete the printer
        painter.end()

        


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

So what is causing this problem? May this be a bug or am i missing something here?

Comment: This is caused by a change in Qt6, which returns a *copy* of the pixmap, not a pointer to the actual one. Due to this, using `label.pixmap()` requires keeping a reference, otherwise it will be destroyed by the garbage collection. Just create a temporary variable: `pixmap = self.label.pixmap()` and `painter = QPainter(pixmap)`.

Comment: Hmm, so atleast the app runs when i implement the fix. But the screen is black and the error still persists. And as far as i understood the documentation `Qpainter(QPaintDevice *device)` still requires a pointer to the pixmap? So what would be a way to get it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: if you did what explained above, it should work as expected. You did create the local `pixmap` variable in the same function used to create the QPainter()`, didn't you? Also, the pixmap must be obviously set *again* in the label after the `painter.end()` (since, as said, it's a copy).

Comment: So i basically HAVE to set the pixmap every time i want to update/change it? Btw what i meant is that the QPaint object is expecting a pointer to the pixmap not the pixmap itself. Thats atleast what i found on google. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Yes, it must be a "pointer" (or reference, in python terms), because the painter doesn't take ownership; besides, since you need to set again the pixmap on the label, you'd need it anyway. And, yes, with Qt6 it is a requirement to set it every time it's updated. Be aware, though, that if you plan on creating a widget that implements custom painting (possibly, dynamically), QLabel is probably *not* a good choice. Just use a basic QWidget, override its `paintEvent()`, and directly do the drawing there using `painter = QPainter(self)` instead of using a pixmap (unless you *do* need a pixmap).